Low audio on microphone and speakers on Ubuntu both 22.04 and 24.04
The speakers and especially the microphone on my ThinkPad T14 Gen 5 (Intel Core Ultra 5 processor) have a very low volume. Tried something here and there but couldn't make them work properly.
Some useful details:

installed Ubuntu 24.04 on the TP T14 and encountered the issue;
swapped the SSD of the T14 with another from a T460s where Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is installed;
issue is not occurring on the T460s where Ubuntu 24.04 is now running;
issue occurs on the T14 where Ubuntu 22.04 is now running.

From the details above I am led to think that it is an hardware/drivers related problem.
Note that when overdrived with the pulse audio tool both microphone and speaker can work properly but I would like them to work fine without any particular adjustments.
Suggestions..?
Edit:
I am integrating the generic information above.
I noticed that on alsamixer runned on the T460s with Ubuntu 24.04 it says that the card in use is "PipeWire" and the chip is "PipeWire" as well. Meanwhile on the T14 with Ubuntu 22.04 it says "sof-hda-dsp" is used a card and "Realtek ALC257" as a chip. Then, I thought I should try and run pipewire on the T14. Running pipewire on such machine with Ubuntu 22.04 gives me the following output:
[W][00080.900317] mod.rt       | [     module-rt.c:  538 set_nice()] could not set nice-level to -11: Permission denied
[E][00080.900672] mod.protocol-native | [module-protocol-:  660 lock_socket()] server 0x5f7018788490: unable to lock lockfile '/run/user/1000/pipewire-0.lock': Resource temporarily unavailable (maybe another daemon is running)
[E][00080.900764] pw.conf      | [          conf.c:  560 load_module()] 0x5f701876f270: could not load mandatory module "libpipewire-module-protocol-native": Resource temporarily unavailable
[E][00080.900931] default      | [      pipewire.c:  123 main()] failed to create context: Resource temporarily unavailable

I add that before doing anything I runned sudo apt install pipewire* as well as sudo apt istall pulseaudio*, just to be sure to have everything that is needed.
Last thing, running pulseadio on teh T14 gives me the following output:
W: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
E: [pulseaudio] socket-server.c: bind(): Address already in use
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-native-protocol-unix" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: D-Bus name org.pulseaudio.Server already taken.
N: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: Could not find org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.RegisterBatteryProvider(), is bluetoothd started with experimental features enabled (-E flag)?


I also have the same issue with Intel Core Ultra 5 on my huawei matebook 14 2024. I noticed when I tried the bootable installer of 24.04 there's no sound, while on 24.10 there was a sound. You can dig through 24.10 to know what it has that 24.04 doesn't.
Edit: I installed 24.10 and it's fixed this issue.
